# php file showing output from a different file

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am very new to PHP programming. I am trying to write this custom php code in Drupal and seeing this weird behavior. Basically I have two php files which users can hit and the first php file is showing output from the second one. I am not including (include) the second file in the first one.

Home.php - The first file (outputs 'why am i executing' at the end)

```
<?php include 'HomeView.BL.inc';
  //Other links to access second file 
?>
```

HomeView.BL.inc

```
<?php
include 'db.inc';
include 'dao.inc'; - has a class called IDA_Map
?>
```

FacultyInternshipDetail.php - The second file

```
<?php 
include 'InternshipDetailView.BL.inc';
?>
```

InternshipDetailView.BL.inc

```
<?php
echo "why am i executing";
include 'db.inc';
include 'dao.inc';
?>
```

Apart from the output from the second file, I am also seeing this error - Cannot redeclare class IDA_Map.

I have read in other posts about 'include_once' but didn't expect re-declaration error since the class (IDA_Map) is declared once per request.

Thank you.

Comment: always use `include_once` when referencing class source.  Always use `.php` file endings and not `.inc`(unless you have logical .htaccess blocking external access to any .inc files).

Comment: Thanks. So I changed include to include_once for dao.inc. and it removes the re-declaration error. What is the life time of variables/classes declared in the included file. I thought they live only for that browser request.

Comment: It lives to the end of that script execution.  But if you include it multiple times in a single execution(either intentionally, or unintentionally via nested includes) you will get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flip all these to `require_once`.

```
<?php require_once'HomeView.BL.inc';
  //Other links to access second file 
?>
```

HomeView.BL.inc

```
<?php
require_once'db.inc';
require_once'dao.inc'; - has a class called IDA_Map
?>
```

FacultyInternshipDetail.php

```
<?php 
require_once'InternshipDetailView.BL.inc';
?>
```

InternshipDetailView.BL.inc

```
<?php
echo "why am i executing";
require_once'db.inc';
require_once'dao.inc';
?>
```

include breaks when you try to include the same file twice.
Also look up composer and into using a php framework so you dont have to worry about any of this!